# How calculate a value using a previous values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate a value in a pandas dataframe using the previous value. Given the values below:

| year | sex | age | pxt | lxt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | m | 0 | m | x |
| 2000 | m | 1 | n | y |
| 2000 | m | 2 | o | z |

```
x = 1 (by definition)

y = x * m

z = y * n
```

I tried to use the .shift(1) method, which worked for the pxt, but since the lxt is calculated iterativly, this did not work in this case.

And yes, data are grouped by year and sex.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) filling with your starting value, then [`cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html):

```
df['lxt'] = df['pxt'].shift(fill_value=1).cumprod()
```

Example output:

```
   year sex  age  pxt  lxt
0  2000   m    0   10    1
1  2000   m    1   20   10
2  2000   m    2   30  200
```

Comment: This is indeed a very elegant solution. I didn't manage the groupby part, but I introduced a loop to run through every group indivdually. Another issue I faced, is a few steps down the line, I have to sum all "lxt" equal or above in the same year, sex, age group. That is, the additional column would be 211, 210, 200. Is there also such an elegant solution?

Comment: To apply this per group `df['pxt'].groupby('group').transform(lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=1).cumprod())`

Comment: For the other issue, please ask a new question.